# Javascript: Wrong width of a layer

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm working with D3.js and I want to know the width of the layer where I'm going to create the graphic. This width can be diferente so I have no defined a width especifically.

Making a test with React and D3.js in CodeSandbox trying to get the width o a layer without width. This is the layer:

[image]

How you can see I've got a layer with an id only. If I try to know it's width width D3.js or javascript with this code:

```
console.log(
  "width: " + d3.select("#" + this.props.idContainer).style("width")
);
console.log(
  "width2: " +
    document.querySelector("#" + this.props.idContainer).clientWidth
);
```

The result get it is:

[image]

Perfect!!! Everything works fine!!! But ... If I try to do the same running my application which is made with React and using D3 like the test in Codesandbox, with the same browser!!! I've got this values!!!

First, we will see the layer which I want to know it's width ...

[image]

And this is the code to know the width of the layer in my application:

```
console.log("WIDTH: " + d3.select("#" + this.props.idContainer).style("width"));
console.log(
  "width2: " +
    document.querySelector("#" + this.props.idContainer).clientWidth
);
```

The results that I've got are...

[image]

It's amazing!!! How is that possible? How can I know the width of a layer in my application? How is that possible that with the same code in CodesanBox I've got the width correctly and in my application I've got bad values?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect. but if  it returns zero, sounds like it is not visible on the page.

Comment: Hi @epascarello!!!! Thanks for your answer!!! It works in Codesanbox but not in my application. It's probably that you are right because initially this layer is hidden. But, dispite of it, the consult of the width is after to make the layer visible again. I don't know what happend exactly, because how I said, the consult I make it when the layer is visible :(((Thanks for your appreciated help!!!